# Joomla - Не распознаёт код php при создании модуля

Tags: joomla, php, изображения

Здравствуйте!

Joomla 2.5.8
Требуется элементарная операция - вывести в определённой позиции картинку.

Для этого создаю модуль (тип - HTML-код), прикрепляю к позиции, прописываю код в редакторе (пробовал TinyMCE, CodeMirror и без редактора).
Решил предусмотреть, чтоб ссылка универсальной.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/image.png" alt="Изображение" width="200" height="200" border="0" />
```

Но при выводе страницы код php браузером не распознаётся, т.е. изображение не показывается и в коде путь выводится, как написано выше.

Подскажите, я делаю глупость?
Вроде для дураков написано, что модуль называется "HTML-код", а типа я php вставляю.
Или, чтоб вывести изображение, прописывая в редакторе Joomlы, нужно использовать только html-код без php вставок.

Или я просто неправильно делаю такую операцию.

И ещё небольшой вопрос. В TinyMCE он всегда обрамляет текст тегами параграфа или заголовков? С этими дополнительными тегами придётся смириться?

Comment: Вроде HTML эт не php, думаю стоит просто на HTML`е начепятать и заработает) з.ы. HTML - разметка страници, PHP - выполняемый на стороне сервера скрипт :) ваш дедушко мороз :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. в модуль HTML код - только HTML. PHP не пройдет. Если нужно позарез, чтобы исполнялся, надо писать свой модуль. Это просто.
2. скорее всего, обрамление тегами  рулится в настройках плагина TinyMCE.

С Наступившим 0x7DD !

Comment: Благодарю! С наступившим Новым годом!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на "еще небольшой вопрос" - скачайте последнюю версию TinyMCE и настройте выбор тега `<p>` или `<br>`. Далее, существуют и другие редакторы, в частности JCE. Касательно заголовков, то действительно - кругом один `<strong>`. Но можно отключить редактор и вводить код без его помощи.

Comment: Благодарствую, с прошедшими праздниками!